# How to ensure jQuery at the global level in a React component?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, froala

I am using froala editor in my React application which requires jQuery to be available at a global level. Now I know I can add below to my webpack file to ensure same:

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery"
 })
]
```

but I don't want this to be part of my webpack config, is there a way I can pass same mapping (defined above) to my React component that is rendering froala editor?

I came across options like:

```
 window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

mentioned here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2180#issuecomment-196048732

but I am unable to figure out how can declare this in froala editor component as window is accessible only after component has mounted.

Comment: You can use the `expose-loader` to expose the `jQuery` and `$` variables - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

Comment: how about just adding the jQuery cdn in your html page above your webpack bundle?